# No suitable driver found (Mas o driver esta la !)

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, java-ee, jdbc

Galera, fiz uma primeira aplicação pelo site da Caelum em Java EE, uma agenda, e tudo certo, tudo bem, adicionei contatos ao MYSQL tranquilamente na parte Java da apostila, o driver do JDBC funcionou tudo certinho e etc... Mas quando fui para o Java EE, o programa funciona perfeitamente, exceto quando clico em "gravar", ele diz que nao foi encontrado nenhum driver, no entanto, eu adicionei o driver da mesma maneira que na aplicação Java, pelo Build path-add to build path, não sei qual o problema, aqui estão os links das aulas:

http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/servlets/
http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/bancos-de-dados-e-jdbc/

e meu código... Está atualizado, agora que o problema ja foi resolvido. Bastou adicionar o método try/catch a classe AdicionarContatoServlet após o Class.forname que foi adicionado a classe ConnectionFactory !

```
package minha.agenda.ozzy;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectionFactory{
    public Connection getConnection () throws ClassNotFoundException{
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            return DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:mysql://localhost/bDados", "gabrielDados", "25120107");
        } catch(SQLException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

package minha.agenda.ozzy;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class Contato {
    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private String email;
    private String end;
    private Calendar dataNascimento;

    public Long getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome(){
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome){
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email){
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEndereco(){
        return end;
    }
    public void setEndereco(String end){
        this.end = end;
    }

    public Calendar getDataNascimento(){
        return dataNascimento;
    }
    public void setDataNascimento(Calendar dataNascimento){
        this.dataNascimento = dataNascimento;
    }
}

package minha.agenda.ozzy;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ContatoDao {
    private Connection connection;

    public ContatoDao() throws ClassNotFoundException{
        this.connection = new ConnectionFactory().getConnection();
    }
    public void adiciona(Contato contato){
        String sql = "insert into contatos"+
                    "(nome, email, endereco, dataNascimento)"+
                    "values (?,?,?,?)";

        try{
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            stmt.setString(1,contato.getNome());
            stmt.setString(2,contato.getEmail());
            stmt.setString(3,contato.getEndereco());
            stmt.setDate(4, new Date(
                        contato.getDataNascimento().getTimeInMillis()));

            stmt.execute();
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

package minha.agenda.ozzy;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

@WebServlet("/adicionaContato")
public class AdicionaContatoServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void service (HttpServletRequest request,
                            HttpServletResponse response)
                            throws IOException, ServletException{

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String nome = request.getParameter("nome");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String end = request.getParameter("end");
        String dataEmTexto = request.getParameter("dataNascimento");
        Calendar dataNascimento = null;

        try {
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(dataEmTexto);
            dataNascimento = Calendar.getInstance();
            dataNascimento.setTime(date);
        } catch (ParseException e){
            out.println("Erro de conversão de data");
            return;
        }

        Contato contato = new Contato();
        contato.setNome(nome);
        contato.setEmail(email);
        contato.setEndereco(end);
        contato.setDataNascimento(dataNascimento);

        ContatoDao dao = null;
        try{
            dao = new ContatoDao();
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dao.adiciona(contato);

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("Contato" + contato.getNome() + "adicionado com sucesso!");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Adiciona Contatos </h1>

    <form action ="adicionaContato">
        Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" /><br />
        Email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
        Endereço: <input type="text" name="end" /><br />
        Data de Nascimento: <input type="text" name="dataNascimento" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Gravar" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tente adicionar o seguinte código logo antes da linha do `return DriverManager...`, dentro do try: `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

Comment: Tentei cara, mas tive que alterar varios codigos das outras classes e... acabou nao funcionando tambem !

Comment: O que te fez ter que mudar outras classes? Foi o código acima que eu pedi para adicionar?

Comment: Está usando algum Container Web? Qual? Se estiver usando, será que o jar do MySQL não precisa estar em alguma pasta do Container para ele carregar no `ClassLoader`?

Comment: Pelo que vi da apostila, ele usa o Tomcat, você precisa colocar o jar do MySQL Connector dentro da pasta lib do Tomcat (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610277/tomcat-does-not-recognize-the-mysql-jar-library).

Comment: @Math, sim cara, assim que mudei o ConnectionFactory tive que mudar Contato e ContatoDao...

Comment: @Wakim, o pior é que eu ja tentei isso também porém... Sem sucesso!

Comment: @Math, consegui resolver o erro que estava dando e sua solução deu resultado ! O que é o método Class.forname ? o que ele faz, poderia me explicar por favor ? Obrigado !

Comment: @user3632011 estou marcando sua pergunta como duplicada de uma outra similar. Vou tentar elaborar melhor minha resposta lá pois não está muito aprofundada, mas vai ter que ser um pouco mais tarde pois estou trabalhando hoje.